# Angular RxJS combine multiple dependant GET requests when first request returns

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, angular-httpclient

Let's say I have a Student with two properties: courseIds, courses.

```
export interface IStudent {
  courseIds: number[];
  courses: ICourse[];
}

export interface ICourse {
  name: string;
}
```

When the page loads I issue a GET request to retrieve a Student where only the courseIds are populated. Then I want to validate these Id's and make an unknown number of aditional GET requests to a diferent endpoint to retrieve his Courses.
In the end I want to have a Student object with populated Courses array.

I got this far:

```
httpClient.get<IStudent>(url)
  .pipe(
    map(student => {
      const validIds = [];
      student.courseIds.forEach(id => {
        if (isValid(id)) {
          validIds.push(id);
        }
      }
      return validIds;
    }),
    ???
  ).subscribe(
    ???
  );
```

Question marks indicate where I'm stuck. How can I implement this using Observables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pipe you can `map` and filter your valid id's before using `switchMap` and `forkJoin` to get an array of ICourse back.

```js
httpClient.get<IStudent>(url)
  .pipe(
    map(student => student.courseIds.filter((id: number) => isValid(id))),
    switchMap((ids: number[]) => forkJoin(ids.map(id => httpClient.get<ICourse>(id))))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (data: ICourse[]) => {
      /* use your course array */
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: (error) => console.log(error),
  }
);
```

You would probably want to split the http service classes up so you have clean 'gets' and do the stitching in a component service class. Then you just need to subscribe or use the async pipe in the component.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fuk6oe?devtoolsheight=60)